# Generating simple statistics from live streaming with Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5

Tags: flash, amazon-web-services, flash-media-server, usage-statistics

I have created a live stream using Amazon Web Services and Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5.

I can log into Flash Media Administration Console and see how many connects/disconnects I've had, but I can't seem to find a place where I can see simple stats such as  unique viewers, or the amount of time each connection was connected.

It seems that this is not default; but I would image there is code I can put into the XML files to generate these statistics. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through various sources, I've discovered that with HTTP Streaming and Amazon Web Services, the stream gets recorded and the content is served by Apache and FMS has no role in that, so no stats are recorded.